# Expokit: undefined method `target_installation_results'

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, expo

I am having this error after creating a project with expo init, ejecting my project and cd into my ios folder then run pod install.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by updating my OS to macOS Catalina 10.15.3